# Removing the void specializations for std::future and std::promise

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, future, c++17

With regards to the paper which describes removing the void specializations for std::future and std::promise [P0241R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0241r0.html).  This may be a stupid question but the proposed solution is to remove the void specialization entirely, but then what are people expected to do when they want to instantiate a `std::future<void>`object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the reference, this would be possible [if `void` were a regular type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html).

```
void get_value() {
    void x;
    return x;
}
```

This is the way it works in some other languages, so it's not without precedent.  In other languages it's called the "unit" type, because it has exactly one possible value.  (Other languages also have the "null" type, which has no possible values, so if you try to create one you get an error.  It's named "null" but it's unrelated to null pointers.)

Comment: To directly answer the "what are people expected to do" question - they _do nothing different_.  `future<void>` doesn't go away, it merely doesn't need specialization.

Comment: @DrewDormann: From what I understand you would have to make some changes eventually, since removing the `std::promise<void>` specialization would mean that the `set_value()` function no longer exists, and you would have to call `set_value({})` instead.

Comment: The `void x` declaration is invalid, yet as a consolation prize the `return` *void-expression* construct is valid in both C and C++, e.g. you could write `return get_value();` in some other function. It doesn't have anything to do with the `future<void>` problem per se, but is a useful way to write self-documenting code that means "this is the action meant to be performed when exiting this function". It may be a matter of style/preference, and I find it a sometimes-useful of an idiom, especially on simpler C compilers that use it as the sole tail optimization hint (otherwise they don't do it).

Answer (score 0):

Having tinkered with implementing the TS, it seems possible to avoid specializing for void if the implementation does some clever things with enable_if, e.g.

```
template <class R>
R future<R>::get()
{
  return shared().get();
}

template <class R>
class shared_state {
  ...
  R get()
  {
    wait();
    if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<V, void>) {
      return *_value;
    }
  }

  template <typename V = value_t, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<V, void>, V>* = nullptr>
  void set_value(const V& value)
  {
    ...
  }

  template <typename V = value_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<V, void>, V>* = nullptr>
  void set_value()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The purpose of a std::future is to know when a process with no actual value to return has ended. So basically it's a synchronization tool.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.